# In my Fragment, onBackPressed is called before onCreateView is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I run Random test(Monkey test) and it found a crash regarding **kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException**.

I have `lateinit var videoEditorView` in my **Fragment** and it is initialized in **onCreateView()**.

My `onBackPressed()` calls `onRelease()`.

In my `onRelease()`:

```
override fun onRelease() {
    super.onRelease(){
    videoEditorView.release()
}
```

Problem is, sometimes, onBackPressed seems called before onCreateView()

Is it occasionally happening? If so, is there any way to avoid this by adding unit-test or prevention code.

Comment: Could you please post your whole class so we can see the code :)

Comment: What is `onRelease()`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce let's say it is custom method.

Comment: Okay, then your custom method code is bugged. :P

Comment: I thinks so. I am looking into checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize view or other property in **Fragment** `onViewCreated()`. Thats means your view is ready